# How do I record a ~45 minute 1080p video with external mic?

Tags: file-system, video, 4.4-kitkat, video-recording

I am currently using the camcorder function that comes with [lgcamera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=rubberbigpepper.lgCamera&hl=en) because it allows me to use the microphone as the source of sound input. But I found that it stops when the recording size reaches 1.9GB (or 2.0GiB in the linux world, or about 16 minutes). I believe this is an arbitrary limit set by Android for apps? I googled and found some people reporting the same file size limit problem.

Is it possible to get around this file limitation problem (I have nexus 5)?
or is there a recording app that would break down the video into smaller sizes? The external mic is a requirement for me though.

If you know how to use external mic that with the native video recording app (1 hour recording limit), that would be even better. [soundabout](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.woodslink.android.wiredheadphoneroutingfix&hl=en) did not work for me.

## Reference:

People complaining about the limit:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1714021

Comment: Please be careful about asking for app recommendations. They are not welcome here. Instead, focus on the problem that you're trying to solve.

Comment: Changed the question a bit.

Comment: How is your memory card formatted? FAT has a 2GB limit, whereas FAT32 supports files up to 4GB.

Comment: @onik There is no memory card slot for Nexus 5.

Comment: I've recorder 6 GB videos on Sony Xperia. Must be the filesystem limit.

Answer (score 1):

I emailed Google about this here is the response I got:

"Thank you for contacting Google. I appreciate your patience with me as I look into this issue. It seems as though the limit placed on the video data file of 2gb is written into the android operating system. This is in effect on all types of android devices.
I have researched a few video control apps, they follow the same rule and stop at 1.9-2gb. At this time I do not believe there is a work around for this issue. I do not have software update information available either. Some of the research I have done points to a possible legislative law that limits the video recording time of mobile devices as it takes away from video recorders."

Comment: That sound very, very improbable to me. Which state's limits would apply to global OS? What if my country banned taking photos as it takes away from cameras? I don't believe that a bit. Thanks for sharing though.