# How do I record 4k video beyond 5 minute limit in Samsung S6?

Tags: video-recording

4K/UHD video recording is gorgeous, but unfortunately the phone has a built in limit of 5 minutes. Not sure if this is for reasons of overheating, or something else. I have plenty of storage.

Is there a way to bypass this? (At my own risk)

Comment: There is some concern from Google that this is imposed by the government: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/57329/how-do-i-record-a-45-minute-1080p-video-with-external-mic

Comment: Related for HTC 10: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/171666/htc-10-removing-the-6-minutes-limit-for-4k-video-uhd

Comment: Of Interest: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/68886/65470